# How to append input data to props in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to add a user input string value to a props array in my Vue.js component using the splice() method but I get an empty array. Can someone please help find a way to merge props array with a user input value from the select tag?

Blade:

```
<briefing-signup form_name="new-york-25.01.19-blog" :tags="['TT: i-nexus: Breakfast meeting - New York', 'Blog']" event="Hoshin/Strategy Execution Executive Briefing | New York, 29th Jan 2019" v-cloak></briefing-signup>
```

Vue component:

```
       <form>
                  <b-field label="Select a session">                       
                    <b-select placeholder="Which session?" 
                          v-model="form.session" expanded>
                      <option                           
                          value="1"
                          key="1">
                          Attend 1
                      </option>
                      <option                           
                          value="2"
                          key="2">
                          Attend 2
                      </option>                          
                    </b-select>                         
                  </b-field>                     

                 <button>Register</button>              
        </form>
```

Vue component script part:

```
<script>
export default {
    props: ['tags'],

    data() {
        return {             
            form: new Form({                    
                session: '',     
                tags: this.tags.splice(1, 0, this.session)               
            })                             
        }
    },      

    methods: {        

    }
}
```

Comment: your line with `splice` adds the element, but then splice does not return the array itself. That's why your issue. Move that line before and then assign it to this.tags

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you please elaborate - what do you mean "move that line before"? Thank you

Comment: added an answer

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the docs for splice.

> Return value
>
> An array containing the deleted elements. If only one element is removed, an array of one element is returned. If no elements are removed, an empty array is returned.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

**EDIT:**

Just change

```
data() {
    return {             
        form: new Form({                    
            session: '',     
            tags: this.tags.splice(1, 0, this.session)               
        })                             
    }
},
```

to

```
data() {
    this.tags.splice(1, 0, this.session);
    return {             
        form: new Form({                    
            session: '',     
            tags: this.tags               
        })                             
    }
},
```

Comment: I am a bit confused, the example from the link you sent indicates that if you pass a second parameter as 0 then no item gets removed and only a new item gets added to the array - here is their example: var months = ['Jan', 'March', 'April', 'June'];
months.splice(1, 0, 'New Item');

Comment: That is correct. Splice can remove specified number of elements starting from a specified index or it can add elements again starting from a specified index. The link I gave is the documentation for the function from Mozilla.

In any case it does not return the array you are calling it on, but rather the removed items (if any).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried moving the splice() line before return and got the undefined in my array: `tags:Array[3]
0:"TT: i-nexus: Breakfast meeting - New York"
1:undefined
2:"i-nexus website"
`

Comment: It is probably undefined because it is not form.session. Though, I tried adding form. to it and still getting undefined :(

Answer (score 0):

`splice` providing elements at the end, adds the elements to the array, at the given index you provided as first parameter,

If you provide the second argument too, different from 0, it replaces the elements.

But in any case, it returns an array of the deleted elements, which in case of adding is an empty array.

So when you do:

```
this.tags.splice(1, 0, this.session)
```

It returns an empty array, and you assign an empty array to tags prop.

You could fix the issue doing something like:

```
export default {
    props: ['tags'],

    data() {
        return {             
            form: new Form({                    
                session: '',     
                tags: Array.isArray(this.tags.splice(1, 0, this.session)) ? this.tags : []               
            })                             
        }
    },      

    methods: {        

    }
}
```

But that's pretty a workaround because your `this.session` exists only inside the `Form` you are creating.

A better approach could be something like:

```
data() {
  const form = new Form({ session: '', tags: this.tags});
  form.tags.splice(1, 0, form.session);   
  return {
    form
  }
},
```

Comment: If I use the second approach I get an empty string in the tags array: `form:Object
company:""
consent:""
email:""
errors:Object
event_name:"Hoshin/Strategy Execution Executive Briefing | New York, 29th Jan 2019"
first_name:""
form_name:"new-york-25.01.19-website"
interested_to_speak:""
job_title:""
last_name:""
loading:false
originalData:Object
phone:""
session:"Attend executive breakfast only"
tags:Array[3]
0:"TT: i-nexus: Breakfast meeting - New York"
1:""
2:"i-nexus website"
isEventModalActive:true`

Comment: Using the first approach returns an undefined string inside the tags array : `tags:Array[3]
0:"TT: i-nexus: Breakfast meeting - New York"
1:undefined
2:"i-nexus website"
isEventModalActive:false`

Comment: It's quite chunky - I could not post it here. Instead I uploaded two files on Google Drive - Form.js and Errors.js https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1C3DKk_16zs6Q7F1UGpUs_gMy-mB1eFBQ?usp=sharing

Comment: I am sorry that's really too broad. Your issue is in the constructor. From the code you have above, it looks like you want always to init your `tags` as the tags you provided plus the session you provided. Move this logic in the constructor then. But again, I am sorry that's getting too broad. THe issue you mentioned above is because of the `splice`

Answer (score 0):

Guess what, I managed to append the select input to the bloody props array by setting v-on:input="SelectChange" on the  tag. And then in my method I put:

```
selectChange() {            
        this.form.tags = Array.isArray(this.form.tags.splice(1, 0, this.form.session)) ? this.form.tags : [];
      },
```

It works, but the problem now is if you select several options it appends each to the array instead of replacing them.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working in the end. Thank you all for your replies and help.

This is the code snippet that works for me:

```
selectChange() { 
          var arrcount = this.form.tags;

          if(arrcount.length !== 2) {
            this.form.tags.splice(2,1);
          }
          this.form.tags.push(this.form.session);
        },
```